# Conductive body of flashlight

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, conductivity

I have a flashlight that seems to use the inside of the metal body to conduct the negative terminal of the LiPo battery inside. The outside isn't conductive - likely anodized.

Would there be adverse effects if the whole body was conductive, i.e. make both the inside and outside conduct the negative terminal? I'm guessing the user wouldn't receive shocks given the low voltage.

The flashlight looks like the following

[image]
<sub>(source: [opticsplanet.com](http://images2.opticsplanet.com/365-240-ffffff/opplanet-guard-dog-security-240-lumen-tactical-metal-rechargeable-flashlight-tl-gd240l.jpg))</sub>

Comment: No adverse effects in electrical point of view. But the metal can develop rust over time.

Comment: If the user grabs on a conductive outer body, wouldn't the resistance increase making the battery less efficient?

Comment: There was no mention of removing the previous points of contact, though.

Comment: @Kar, there is no significant change in the battery-to-load resistance, if the user grabs on a conductive outer body

Comment: Back in the olden days, flashlight bodies were often made of [metal](http://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-photo-old-metal-flashlight-isolated-white-background-image31609635).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about DC, so there is really no skin effect or the like. The whole body of the flashlight is conducting the DC, the external varnish is only for corrosion resistance and "look and feel".

If you scraped off the coating there won't be dangers for the user holding the flashlight. The voltage drop along the case is ridiculously low since the resistance is probably on the milliohm range and the internal batteries+circuitry (even assuming a boost converter of some sort) won't generate more than a few volts maximum.<sup>1</sup>

Moreover the body of the flashlight is probably some aluminium alloy, already fairly resistant to corrosion, and some models *are* made with no protective coating at all, so the conductive surface is exposed to the user.

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>Ok, theoretically I could imagine some idiot el-cheapo manufacturer using a string of some 40 LED in series and using a ~150V output boost converter to power the string, but I still have to see that :-)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Note that in order to receive a shock there needs to a return path through your body. Even if that flashlight used 1000 V inside it would be safe !
Why ? Because it is completely self contained, if you hold it in your hand there is only one connection to the flashlight. In order for you to get a shock the current must be able to flow into and out of your body.

This is why mains connected appliances are dangerous, they have a return path through ground. Yes, the ground your standing on ! It can be conductive enough (even including your shoes etc.) for you to feel the current flow.

If you were able to hover a small distance above the ground, you could safely touch any mains wire as there would be no return path. Since electricians cannot hover either, rubber isolated shoes and gloves help to provide the required high resistance.

In the flashlight case, the flashlight has no connection to ground so there can be no return path.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a EE, but I have a very hard time imagining a scenario where having the outside conduct to the negative terminal a bad thing. I cannot see any way for contact with the positive end of the battery.